# How to bind DOM in vue.js2 for generate tweet in javaScript factory function?

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter, vue.js, vuejs2

How can i bind Document.getElementById in vue.js2. I am using embed tweet with javaScript factory function. its working fine if i only take DOM in .html file and generate tweet in vue file but not working if both is in .vue file. i need to use DOM in my .vue file and binds it with to factory function.

I have tried with ref and v-el but not worked.

```
<template>
  <div class="row" id="home">
      <h3 v-if="msg"><span class="label label-warning">{{msg}}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <!--<div v-for="tweet in tweetHtml">
      <div v-html="tweet"></div>
    </div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="container" ></div> <!-- generated tweet from fun should bind here -->
</template>

<script>
import appService from '../service'
import bus from '../service/bus'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchedTopic: '',
      user_id: '',
      tweets: {},
      tweetHtml: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    // generate tweet with javaScript factory fun <<---=-=-=-=
    twttr.widgets.createTweet('20',
    document.getElementById('container'),  // <<-- what to do to bind container with vue file's div.
    {
      theme: 'light'
    })
    .then( function( el ) {
      console.log('Tweet added.');
    });
  },
  methods: {

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to make but you can use `$refs`, something like this `<div id="container" ref="container"></div>`, and then access it like this `this.$refs.container` - pay attention `this` into twttr object won't be referenced to Vue Instance, so declare before `var self = this` and use `self.$refs.container`

Comment: @BelminBedak i have trie but id didn't worked. i have mentioned it.
and after your comment i have tried it once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just get the DOM node, use ref can work.

twttr? what's this?

Comment: Whats the point posting as answer thing that I already write ?

Comment: I take your point. I didn't see it when I published it, sorry

Comment: @strive.chen look this https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/javascript-create

Comment: @DhruvGoradiya Thanks.